# RemoteServiceServlet is returning null with getThreadLocalRequest()

Tags: java, gwt

I have this line in the constructor of my RemoteServiceServlet

```
userID = getThreadLocalRequest().getRemoteUser();
```

but its throwing NullPointerException because getThreadLocalRequest returns null.

My understanding was that RemoteServiceServlet inherits from HttpServlet and hence should have the HttpReuest object already !!
Do I need to set anything before calling getThreadLocalRequest() in case of GWT?

Comment: I use `getThreadLocalRequest()` with no problems. The problem is somewhere else.

Comment: I got the impression that it was not just me who is facing this problem. A quick google search throws up a few posts with the same issue - https://www.google.com/search?q=gwt+getthreadlocalrequest+returns+null, however none of these had a clear solution

Comment: What I mean is that the problem is not in the line of code that you shared. You need to share more code, unless, of course, David's suggestion has already solved your problem.

Comment: David's suggestion worked. It was returning null only within the constructor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem could be that you are trying to use that method inside the constructor of a servlet. A new servlet instance is not created for each request. Servlet instances are reused across requests. Try calling getThreadLocalRequest() inside a service method instead.